# TV used as monitor crashes whenever a program is dragged onto it. (Application runs fine, TV crashes)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, tv

I am using a Minicomputer that natively runs Windows 10 and has multiple video outputs.  I linked one input to a Roku TV. The other input is hooked to a monitor.  The monitor is the main output and displays perfectly well, and the TV renders fine as well, but if I drag something, such as windows explorer or google chrome to the TV, to the point where it scales up to the higher resolution, it instantly crashes, and I get the disconnected HDMI message on the Roku.  I have no access to the Settings or the command prompt and will likely be given access by the local administrator for a very short time.  I would like to have some ideas on what to do to make it work.  After further diagnosis, the application does not crash the application continues to run on the system, and the monitor disconnects.

I got some testing in when the administrator came by.  It crashed at any resolution, but lowering the resolution from the native to 1080p caused it to flicker instead of immediately crashing, and then crash.  Lowering the resolution to the lowest setting caused instant crashing.  It has been advised I acquire another cable.  Does anyone have any ideas why this might be occurring?  Thank you.

This is not a duplicate of [Dragging an application to the second monitor causes it to crash. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/67135/dragging-an-application-to-the-second-monitor-causes-it-to-crash-why), as answers are not applicable to my situation.  The playback program crashes in the linked question, but in my case, the hardware itself appears to be crashing.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to close this, since the question this is marked as a duplicate of, is a different question, with answers that do not reflect what I am trying to achieve, specifically because those are about issues with a particular program crashing, not the monitor as a whole.

Comment: Duplicate flags are primarily about the answers, have you tried the answers, to the duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, the answers seem to be irrelevant, they're all about an individual application crashing playback, not a crashing monitor.

Comment: I'd like to answer my own question, I found a solution, that is unique to this question, unrelated to the other question.  The answer was to replace the cable, it caused it to work normally.

Comment: Done;  I have removed the meta-commentary from your question.  You might take note of how I attempted to merge your different edits into a single revision.  You don't have to indicate you have "edited" your question.  The system keeps track of revisions we already know you changed your content.  These poor edits are likely the reason the question remained closed as long as it did.  It certainly was a reason for the voting to keep the question close initially.  **I would advise you to go into detail about the reason replacing the cable was the solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the cable out, the monitor no longer crashed when the applications were dragged from one screen to another.  This was a practical fix that I have little understanding of, but it was suggested to me by the IT department, that the oversized HDMI cable initially used, was having issues transmitting signals at that distance, and that a shorter one may rectify the problem.

Please correct me if anyone has a better understanding of why this fix worked.  Thank you.